# Dynamics of a two dimensional differential linear system

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems

Consider the system 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
u\\ 
v
\end{pmatrix}'
=
\begin{pmatrix}
 a & - b \\ 
 b & a
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
u\\ 
v
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I want to find the orbits described by the solutions in function of the values of $u$ and $v$ in $t_0$.

How does one do that?

---

My attempt:

The eigenvalues of the matrix are $a\pm bi$, and the associated eigenvectors are 
$\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
\pm i
\end{pmatrix}$.

Thus the general solution of the system should be $x\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
 i
\end{pmatrix}e^{(a+bi)t}+y\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
- i
\end{pmatrix}e^{(a-bi)t}$

or equivalently, taking the real and imaginary parts of the components, the general solution is $e^{at}\begin{pmatrix}
\sin bt\\ 
\cos bt
\end{pmatrix}x+
e^{at}\begin{pmatrix}
\cos bt\\ 
-\sin bt
\end{pmatrix}y$

Aaand I am stuck. At this point I recall I should do some kind of polar transformate somehow to see that these orbits are spirals, but I can't really figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get
$$
(u+iv)'=(a+ib)(u+iv)
$$
which integrates to
$$
u+iv=(u_0+iv_0)e^{(a+ib)(t-t_0)}
$$

Comment: +1 Right answer, but technically, not integration; it's solving $f'(t)=(a+ib)f(t)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Which is also called the integration of a differential equation.

Comment: Hmm, never seen that term, myself, but I guess it is real.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know the trick of setting $u'=0$ and $v'=0$, which is really $0=au-bv$ and $0=bu+av$?  If you graph those lines and then start drawing your spiral, when you hit the first line, the path changes from inc to dec (or vv) in the $u$ direction.  When you hit the second line, the path changes from inc to dec (or vv) in the $v$ direction.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

Apply a coordinate change to polar coordinates:
$$
\rho^2=u^2+v^2\\
\theta = \arctan \frac{v}{u}
$$
Therefore derivating we have that:
$$
2\rho\rho'=2uu'+2vv'=2u(au-bu)+2v(bu+av)=2b(u^2+v^2)=2b\rho \implies \rho'=b \rho\\
\theta'=\frac{uv'-vu'}{u^2+v^2}=\frac{u(bu+av)-v(au-bu)}{\rho^2}=b
$$
Therefore the general solution is $\begin{pmatrix}\rho\\\theta\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}e^{at}\\bt\end{pmatrix}$, which describes a spiral, either increasing o decreasing depending on the sign of $a$, or a circle if $a=0$.

Comment: ...All of which was already in LutzL's answer, without the polar coordinates trick.